# How to make spacing in list bigger when it is forced to separate into 2 lines?

Tags: html, css

For example, take this simple list:

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
  <li>SOMETHING ELSE</li>
  <li>ANOTHER THING</li>
  <li>ONE MORE THING</li>
  <li>CONTACT
  </li>
</ul>
```

When the width of the screen becomes smaller, the list is forced to spread over 2 lines, and then eventually 3 lines and so forth. My question is how do you increase the vertical space between these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add increase the line-height in the li tag. 
For example: line-height: 32px;

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
  <li>SOMETHING ELSE</li>
  <li>ANOTHER THING</li>
  <li>ONE MORE THING</li>
  <li>CONTACT
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `display: inline-block` instead of `inline` or setting a `line-height` to the `li` like Ricardo suggested.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
  <li>SOMETHING ELSE</li>
  <li>ANOTHER THING</li>
  <li>ONE MORE THING</li>
  <li>CONTACT
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below CSS :

```
li{
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: auto;
}

ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8zceo42/) here